# How to write a loop selection by location and export in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, select-by-location

I would like to be able to make selections in sequence between buffers and surrounding areas. This would lead to areas (polygons) being selected repeatedly by 2 or more buffers and I want to be able to make selections and exports, listing every export to belong to a number (or numbers) of polygons

For instance:

I start by selecting the first line of shapefile A and I want to select all the polygons of shapefile B that are inside of shapefile A (B polygons contained in A), to then export them as shapefile_1.

And this process to be repeated for x records in A to produce more shapefiles (shapefile_1, shapefile_2, ... shapefile_x).

How can this be done in QGIS?